# Using "Show" property in Cesium to turn on and off layers doesn't reflect on viewer

Tags: javascript, cesium

I am visualizing a geoJSON datasource in Cesium.  I have tied it to a checkbox to modify the "show" property in order to turn it on and off after it is added to the viewer (not adding/removing the data source), however it seems like altering the "show" property alone does not actually hide or show the datasource.  This is my function (handleclick is the function tied to the checkbox element):

```
function handleclick(cb) {
if (cb.checked === true) {
    console.log(cb.id + " is checked")
    for (var i in viewer.dataSources._dataSources) {
        if ("chk_" + viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i]._name == cb.id) {  //match checked box to datasource ID
            viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i].show =  new Cesium.ConstantProperty(true)  //show layer?             
        }
    }       
} else {
    console.log(cb.id + " is unchecked")
    for (var i in viewer.dataSources._dataSources) {
        if ("chk_" + viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i]._name == cb.id) { 
            viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i].show =  new Cesium.ConstantProperty(false)  //hide layer?                
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to update the viewer somehow after the "show" property (referenced at https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GeoJsonDataSource.html#show) is changed in order for the data to be hidden?

Answer (score 2):

The function works, just need to change the show property to the actual boolean value:

```
viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i].show =  true
```

Comment: That's correct.  Generally we discourage use of "private" variables, ones with leading underscores like `_dataSources[i]`.  Instead you can use things like `viewer.dataSources.length` and `viewer.dataSources.get(i)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The reason I'm using the underscores is that what the JSON properties show on my console log.   Is that a setting I would change?